# Difference between two columns of date of two different table with hibernate criteria

Tags: sql, hibernate-criteria

I have a sql query like :

```
SELECT 
    e.a, 
    c.b, 
    DATEDIFF(c.b,e.a), 
    DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),e.a) 

FROM E e 
LEFT JOIN C c 

WHERE ( DATEDIFF(c.b, e.a) > 10 OR DATEDIFF(c.b, e.a) IS NULL )
AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), e.a) > 10
```

How can I do this using hibernate criteria query..

Comment: Did get the answer, i'm also looking for the same

Comment: anybody have the answer same problem here

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea : you could create a sql view like the one you wrote and then query this view.
It might even be more efficient than using hibernate.